# Como puedo cambiar varias piezas de codigo de html con java scrip a la vez

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas estoy creando un catalogo ya esta casi terminado pero me percate que es muy cansado que para poder corregir un precio tenga que utilizar html y como debo corregir varios precio en una misma pagina debo cambiar piezas de código muy pequeño a hora e solucionado hasta los momentos con piezas como esta

```
<scripts>document.getElementById("a50").innerHTML = "$0";
document.getElementById("airpods12").innerHTML = "$0";  
document.getElementById("airpods11").innerHTML = "$0";
document.getElementById("airpodspro").innerHTML = "$0";  
document.getElementById("beasts").innerHTML = "$0";
document.getElementById("beaststudio").innerHTML = "$0";
document.getElementById("beaststudio3").innerHTML = "$0";</scripts>



<!-- Product details -->
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="product-details">
                            <h2 class="product-name">A50</h2>
                            
                            <div>
                                <h3 id="a50" class="product-price"> $13 </h3>
                                <span class="product-available">Disponible</span>
                            </div>
                            <p>Audifonos wave  perfectos para la pc o consola con micrófono para las partidas en linea y también para las video llamadas gran calidad de audio a un gran precio.</p>
                                                    

                            <ul class="product-links">
                                <li>Category:</li>
                                <li><a href="../../storage/Audifonos/Audifonos.html">Audifonos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Product details -->


<div class="product-body">
                                <p class="product-category">Audifonos</p>
                                <h3 class="product-name"><a href="Hogou E02.html">HOGOU e02</h3>
                                <h4 id="hogoue02" class="product-price">$2 </h4>
                                <div class="product-rating">
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-btns">
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

el codigo tiene varias interacciones como esas en html y  cada vez que hago eso en js que esta en otro documento no reconoce ninguno y no realiza los cambios debido a que son muchos productos busco una forma de realizar todos los cambios a la vez que puedo hacer

Comment: Hmmm veo 2 errores, el primero es que es `javascript` no `java scrip`, java y javascript son cosas totalmente diferentes, el segundo error es que la etiqueta `<scripts></scripts>` no existe.

Comment: eso solo fue para poder publicar como explique en el final de la pregunta se encuentra en un archivo js que llamo en los html

Comment: Vale, una pregunta, de que manera corriges los codigos?, ya que si los editas en tu codigo y recargas la pagina o simplemente usas la consola entonces creo que te falta algo muy importante, en primer lugar... supongo es un ejemplo de alguna pagina para comprar productos, o se supone ese es el fin ultimo, entonces lo mejor es tener un panel de administracion el cual seas el unico que pueda acceder y que mediante ese panel tu directamente puedas cambiar los valores de los codigos.

Comment: Lo otro es... no veo tecnologias como `MySQL` , `MongoDB`, `Cassandra` o alguna otra como para mantener guardada esa informacion, si tu modificas la informacion nada mas asi cuando recargues la pagina los valores se resetearan, la idea es tener alguna base de datos asi sea local para guardar esos valores y que no los pierdas al momento de simplemente recargar la pagina. esos valores son los que cargarias al momento de cargar la pagina, y no los de `JS`.

Comment: ok si comprendo esos principios la cosa es que por motivos de normas la idea es desarrollar sin nada de bases de datos crear un catalogo de compras solo con html5 css y Javascript  y pruebo la pagina con liveservert

Comment: Ummm tengo una idea de que puedes hacer, dejame escribo una respuesta al respecto, aunque de todas maneras ten estrictamente en cuenta de que esta respuesta que te voy a dar es solo un ejemplo de practica, es algo que **JAMAS** debes usar en un proyecto real, si lo haces ten por seguro que te despiden a los minutos. esto es mas que todo porque no se pueden usar `BD` ni backend, pero la idea siempre es tener esa informacion en el backend.

Comment: Gracias en verdad si pero ya ves casos de casos cree que esto no es para un trabajo imagina que cada producto nuevo que creo lo tengo que registrar a antigua no por medio de un modal el cual me cargue los datos por pos y publique el producto eso esta prohibido, así que tengo que crear producto nuevo por producto nuevo

Comment: ¿No te convendría utilizar `querySelectorAll` como: `document.querySelectorAll('.product-price').forEach(function (e) {e.innerHTML = "$0";});`?

Comment: intentare con ese gracias por la idea

Comment: @Firefly tu comentario es correcto eso resolvió mi problema por favor responde a la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira, no se si conoces `angular`, es un `framework` buenisimo el cual sirve para desarrollar aplicaciones de todo tipo dinamicas, pero principalmente para la web.

Oviamente tu no puedes usar `angular`, asi que mi idea es simplemente **NO** usar angular, pero tomar prestado de angular ciertos conceptos muy buenos.

Por ejemplo, tu en angular puedes vincular algo que se le llama `modelo` con la `vista`, el cual el modelo seria el `.ts` (los datos), y la vista seria el `HTML`.

Vamos a ver este mismo comportamiento pero en javascript puro, naturalmente no sera tan comodo como en `angular` pero de algo servira:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

  const products = document.getElementById("products");
  const dinamicTable = document.getElementById("tablaDatos");
  const updateInfo = document.getElementById("update_info");
  let productsData = [
    {
      name: "A50",
      price: "$13",
      available: "Disponible",
      description: "Audifonos wave  perfectos para la pc o consola con micrófono para las partidas en linea y también para las video llamadas gran calidad de audio a un gran precio.",
      subcategory: "Audifonos",
      category: "Accessories"
    },
    {
      name: "G76",
      price: "$17",
      available: "Disponible",
      description: "Telefono de la nasa",
      subcategory: "Telefono",
      category: "Accessories"
    }
  ];
  
  function getTemplate({name, price, available, description, subcategory, category}){
    return `
      <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="product-details">
              <h2 class="product-name">${name}</h2>

              <div>
                  <h3 id="a50" class="product-price">${price}</h3>
                  <span class="product-available">${available}</span>
              </div>
              <p class = "product-description">${description}</p>


              <ul class="product-links">
                  <li>Category:</li>
                  <li><a href="../../storage/Audifonos/Audifonos.html" class = "subcategory">${subcategory}</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class = "category">${category}</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }
  
  function insertRows(rowData){
    rowData.forEach(product =>{
      const row = document.createElement("tr");
      dinamicTable.appendChild(row);
      
      for(let item in product){
        const rowD = document.createElement("td");
        const rowText = document.createTextNode(product[item]);
        rowD.contentEditable = "true";
        rowD.appendChild(rowText);
        row.appendChild(rowD);
      }
    });
    
    updateTable();
  }
  
  function updateRowsDataModel(){
    const rows = Array.from(dinamicTable.children).slice(1);
    const rowsData = [];
    
    rows.forEach(row =>{
      const newData = Object.assign({}, productsData[0]);
      
      Array.from(row.children).forEach((rowText, i) =>{
          newData[Object.keys(newData)[i]] = rowText.textContent;
      });
      
      rowsData.push(newData);
    });
    
    productsData = rowsData;
    updateTable();
  }
  
  function updateTable(){
    products.innerHTML = "";
    productsData.forEach(product => {
      const template = getTemplate(product);
      products.innerHTML += template;
    });
  }
  
  insertRows(productsData);
  updateInfo.addEventListener("click", updateRowsDataModel);

}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#update_info{
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id = "products">
</div>

<table id = "tablaDatos">
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Disponible</th>
    <th>Descripcion</th>
    <th>Subcategoria</th>
    <th>Categoria</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id = "update_info">Actualizar información</button>
```

Bueno, el comportamiento es el siguiente, la idea que tuve es crear una tabla personalizada,  la cual te permitira por medio de su propiedad `contenteditable` poder actualizar los contenidos de tu `HTML` de manera mas comoda, de esta manera no tienes que tocar codigo para poder cambiar los datos que requieras de tu `HTML`.

Si bien es un poco larga la explicacion... quiero resumirlo un poco, este seria el modelo de datos:

```
  let productsData = [
    {
      name: "A50",
      price: "$13",
      available: "Disponible",
      description: "Audifonos wave  perfectos para la pc o consola con micrófono para las partidas en linea y también para las video llamadas gran calidad de audio a un gran precio.",
      subcategory: "Audifonos",
      category: "Accessories"
    },
    {
      name: "G76",
      price: "$17",
      available: "Disponible",
      description: "Telefono de la nasa",
      subcategory: "Telefono",
      category: "Accessories"
    }
  ];
```

Es decir, estos datos al cambiarlos y darle al boton de actualizar te actualizaran automaticamente la vista, estos cambios los veras obviamente si antes haz cambiado algun valor en la tabla.

Esta function:

```
  function getTemplate({name, price, available, description, subcategory, category}){
    return `
      <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="product-details">
              <h2 class="product-name">${name}</h2>

              <div>
                  <h3 id="a50" class="product-price">${price}</h3>
                  <span class="product-available">${available}</span>
              </div>
              <p class = "product-description">${description}</p>


              <ul class="product-links">
                  <li>Category:</li>
                  <li><a href="../../storage/Audifonos/Audifonos.html" class = "subcategory">${subcategory}</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class = "category">${category}</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }
```

Simplemente te devuelve `HTML` dinamico ayudandonos de algo llamado `template strings`, los template strings te permiten renderizar codigo `JS` dentro de un string, mas informacion sobre template strings:

[Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Despues tenemos esta funcion:

```
  function insertRows(rowData){
    rowData.forEach(product =>{
      const row = document.createElement("tr");
      dinamicTable.appendChild(row);
      
      for(let item in product){
        const rowD = document.createElement("td");
        const rowText = document.createTextNode(product[item]);
        rowD.contentEditable = "true";
        rowD.appendChild(rowText);
        row.appendChild(rowD);
      }
    });
    
    updateTable();
  }
```

La cual se encarga de como dice insertar las filas en la vista con el contenido mas actualizado posible.

Para ello utilizamos los metodos:

- `createElement` (permite crear un elemento `HTML`)
- `createTextNode` (permite crear un nodo de texto)
- `appendChild` (permite anadir un elemento HTML previamente creado al final).
- `innerHTML` (es una propiedad, permite tambien anadir o reemplazar codigo html de un contenedor).

Esta funcion de aqui:

```
  function updateRowsDataModel(){
    const rows = Array.from(dinamicTable.children).slice(1);
    const rowsData = [];
    
    rows.forEach(row =>{
      const newData = Object.assign({}, productsData[0]);
      
      Array.from(row.children).forEach((rowText, i) =>{
          newData[Object.keys(newData)[i]] = rowText.textContent;
      });
      
      rowsData.push(newData);
    });
    
    productsData = rowsData;
    updateTable();
  }
```

Lo que hace es actualizar el modelo de datos usando como base los datos que hay en la tabla, y debido a que estos se encuentran organizados podemos ayudarnos de esto para modificar el modelo de datos y luego con ayuda de la llamada a `updateTable` actualizamos tambien la vista en consecuencia.

Ademas notemos que tenemos dos cosas al final:

```
insertRows(productsData);
updateInfo.addEventListener("click", updateRowsDataModel);
```

El primero nos sera util en caso de que tengamos de primera mano informacion que insertar en el documento, es decir, si el modelo de datos **NO** esta vacio de esta manera se inserta de manera dinamica la informacion el base al modelo de datos al momento que cargue la pagina.

La segunda parte es para anadirle un evento oyente de tipo `click` al boton de actualizar, pues en este caso este boton refrescara el `modelo` y la `vista` (recordemos que como no es `angular` el modelo no esta exactamente ligado asi que para actualizarlo tendremos que usar el boton).

El cual cada vez que se ejecute ejecutara la funcion `updateRowsDataModel`
y esta a su vez al final de su ejecucion llamara a la funcion encargada de actualizar la vista.

Por el momento esto serviria para modificar datos o insertarlos de manera mas comoda, sin embargo queda a tu criterio la construccion de un boton de insertar o eliminar filas.

Comment: Posdata: recuerda, las celdas tienen un `contenteditable` asi que dandole click a las celdas de la tabla podras escribir en ellas y por tanto modificar esta informacion.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.product-price').forEach(function (e) {e.innerHTML = "$0";});
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [answer]